# How to move carts item to a new sessions after login?

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I use passportjs, express-session and react.

I store carts item in the session. and i use express-mysql-session so if i add new cart it will store in session and mysql database.

but.....

Iam make loggin using passportjs and iam using express-session, so when user loggin its make a new session.

> So is there a way to retrieve data in the previous session? or i need
>   to store my carts in localstorage ?

**Here is my AddToCart**

```
export const addToCart = (req,res) =>{

    if(req.sessionID || req.user){


    let queryCheckCart = `select crt.id from carts as crt where crt.session_id = '${req.sessionID}'`;
    let queryCheckCartList = `select ci.product_id,ci.product_variant_id,ci.product_attribute_id from cart_items as ci where cart_id = (select crt.id from carts as crt where crt.session_id = '${req.sessionID}') and ci.product_id = ${req.body.product_id} and ci.product_variant_id = ${req.body.product_variant_id} and ci.product_attribute_id = ${req.body.product_attribute_id}`;


    let queryAddToCart = `INSERT INTO carts (session_id,active) values ('${req.sessionID}',1)`;
    let queryAddCartList = `INSERT INTO cart_items (product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity) SELECT ${req.body.product_id},${req.body.product_variant_id},${req.body.product_attribute_id},(SELECT crt.id  from carts as crt where crt.session_id = '${req.sessionID}'),1 where (select pa.stock from product_attribute as pa where pa.id = ${req.body.product_attribute_id}) >= 1 `;

    let queryInsertAll = `${queryAddToCart}; ${queryAddCartList};`;

    let queryUpdateCartList = `UPDATE cart_items as ci set ci.quantity = ci.quantity+1 where 
    ci.cart_id = (select crt.id from carts as crt where crt.session_id = '${req.sessionID}') and ci.product_id = ${req.body.product_id} and ci.product_variant_id = ${req.body.product_variant_id} and ci.product_attribute_id = ${req.body.product_attribute_id} and (select pa.stock from product_attribute as pa where pa.id = ${req.body.product_attribute_id}) >= ci.quantity+1 `;

    let queryFindCartList =`select 
    ci.id as cart_items_id,
    p.name as product_name,
    p.slug as product_slug,
    p.description,
    p.regular_price,
    c.name as category_name,
    c.slug,
    ct.name as category_type,
    ct.slug as category_type_slug,
    pd.discount_percentage,
    pd.discount_value,
    p.id as product_id,
    pa.id as product_attribute_id,
    pv.id as product_variant_id,
i.link,i.caption,i.alt,pa.size,pa.stock,crt.active as cart_status,ci.quantity from products as p 
left join product_category as pc on p.id = pc.product_id 
left join categories as c on pc.category_id = c.id 
left join product_variant as pv on p.id = pv.product_id
left join category_type as ct on pv.category_type_id = ct.id
left join product_discount as pd on pd.id = 
(SELECT pd1.id from product_discount as pd1 where p.id = pd1.product_id and now() between pd1.valid_from and pd1.valid_until)
left join product_image as pi on pi.id = (SELECT pi1.id from product_image as pi1 where pi1.product_id = p.id order by pi1.product_id asc limit 1)
left join images as i on pi.image_id = i.id 
left join product_attribute as pa on p.id = pa.product_id and pv.id = pa.product_variant_id
left join cart_items as ci on pv.id = ci.product_variant_id and p.id = ci.product_id and pa.id = ci.product_attribute_id
left join carts as crt on ci.cart_id = (SELECT crt1.id from carts as crt1 where crt1.session_id = '${req.sessionID}' 
) where crt.session_id = '${req.sessionID}' and ci.quantity <= pa.stock
`;


    let queryChecking = `${queryCheckCart}; ${queryCheckCartList}; ${queryFindCartList};`;


    db.query(queryChecking,(error,result)=>{
        if(error) return res.status(400).json(error);
        if(result[0].length > 0){
            let payload = {
                session_id: req.sessionID,
                cart_id: result[0][0].id
            }
            let dataToken = jwt.sign(payload, keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey, { expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn });
            req.session.carts = dataToken;
            res.cookie("hammerstout_ss", dataToken, { sameSite: true });
        }
        if(result[0].length > 0 && result[1].length === 0 && result[2].length < 15){
            db.query(queryAddCartList,(error,result)=>{
                if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                if (result) {
                    db.query(queryFindCartList, (error, result) => {
                        if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                        let token_cart = {
                                result
                            };



                            let notification = {
                                error: false,
                                message: "ADDED TO YOUR CART.",
                                notification: true
                            }
                            let token_c = jwt.sign(token_cart, keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey, { expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn });
                            return res.status(200).json({ cart_list: result, status: 'OK', notification: notification, token_c});
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
        }
        if (result[0].length === 0 && result[1].length === 0 && result[2].length < 15){
            db.query(queryInsertAll,(error,result)=>{
                if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);

                if (result[0].affectedRows > 0 && result[1].affectedRows > 0){
                    let payload = {
                        session_id: req.sessionID,
                        cart_id: result[0].insertId
                    }
                    let dataToken = jwt.sign(payload, keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey, { expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn });
                    res.cookie("hammerstout_ss", dataToken, { sameSite: true });
                    req.session.carts = dataToken;
                            db.query(queryFindCartList, (error, result) => {
                                if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                                if (result.length > 0) {
                               let token_cart = {
                                        result
                                    };
                                    let notification = {
                                        error: false,
                                        message: "ADDED TO YOUR CART.",
                                        notification: true
                                    }
                                    let token_c = jwt.sign(token_cart, keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey, { expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn });
                                    return res.status(200).json({ cart_list: result, status: 'OK', notification: notification, token_c});
                                }
                            })   
                        }
                 if (result[0].affectedRows === 0){
                    let notification = {
                        error: true,
                        message: "ERROR CART",
                        notification: true
                    }
                    return res.status(400).json({ notification: notification });
                        }
                 if (result[1].affectedRows === 0){
                    let notification = {
                        error: true,
                        message: "IS OUT OF STOCK !",
                        notification: true
                    }
                    return res.status(400).json({  notification: notification});
                        }
            })
        }
         if (result[0].length > 0 && result[1].length > 0 ){
            db.query(queryUpdateCartList,(error,result)=>{
                if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);

                if (result.affectedRows > 0){
                    db.query(queryFindCartList, (error, result) => {
                        if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                           let token_cart = {
                                result
                            };
                            let notification = {
                                error: false,
                                message: "ADDED TO YOUR CART.",
                                notification: true
                            }
                            let token_c = jwt.sign(token_cart, keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey, { expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn });
                            return res.status(200).json({ cart_list: result, status: 'OK', notification: notification, token_c});
                        }
                    }) 
                }
                else if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
                    let notification = {
                        error: true,
                        message: "IS OUT OF STOCK !",
                        notification: true
                    }
                    return res.status(400).json({ notification: notification });
                }
            })
        } if ( result[0].length > 0 && result[2].length >= 15 ){
            let notification = {
                error: true,
                message: "Already the maximum limit",
                notification: true
            }
            return res.status(400).json({ notification: notification });
        }
        // else{
        //     let notification = {
        //         error: true,
        //         message: "ERROR FROM CART",
        //         notification: true
        //     }
        //     return res.status(400).json({ notification: notification });
        // }
    })
    }else{
        let notification = {
            error: true,
            message: "ERROR FROM CART",
            notification: true
        }
        return res.status(400).json({ notification: notification });
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have shared session storage. You can store session data on a database like Redis. Then you will be able to check user session data after each user login and repopulate the cart.

Comment: Iam using express-mysql-session for sessionStore. how can u do repopulate in Redis ? can u give me some articel or example